# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token- JQuery Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

**I have this script that is showing me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error. Funny  thing is that it works flawlessly on another laptop but on the other it doesn't. It's basically a calendar.**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    /* 
   ==========================================================================

       Fullcalendar

     ========================================================================== */



$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {

        left: '',

        center: 'prev, title, next',

        right: 'today agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month'

    },

    buttonIcons: {

        prev: 'font-icon font-icon-arrow-left',

        next: 'font-icon font-icon-arrow-right',

        prevYear: 'font-icon font-icon-arrow-left',

        nextYear: 'font-icon font-icon-arrow-right'

    },

    defaultDate: '2017-01-01',

    editable: true,

    selectable: true,

    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    events: [

        {

            title: 'All Day Event',

            start: '2017-01-01'

        },

        {

            title: 'Long Event',

            start: '2017-01-07',

            end: '2017-01-10',

            className: 'event-green'

        },

        {

            id: 999,

            title: 'Repeating Event',

            start: '2017-01-09T16:00:00',

            className: 'event-red'

        },

        {

            id: 999,

            title: 'Repeating Event',

            start: '2017-01-16T16:00:00',

            className: 'event-orange'

        },

        {

            title: 'Conference',

            start: '2017-01-11',

            end: '2017-01-13',

            className: 'event-coral'

        },

        {

            title: 'Meeting',

            start: '2017-01-12T10:30:00',

            end: '2017-01-12T12:30:00',

            className: 'event-green'

        },

        {

            title: 'Lunch',

            start: '2017-01-12T12:00:00'

        },

        {

            title: 'Meeting',

            start: '2017-01-12T14:30:00',

            className: 'event-red'

        },

        {

            title: 'Happy Hour',

            start: '2017-01-12T17:30:00'

        },

        {

            title: 'Dinner',

            start: '2017-01-12T20:00:00',

            className: 'event-orange'

        },

        {

            title: 'Birthday Party',

            start: '2017-01-13T07:00:00'

        },

        {

            title: 'Click for Google',

            url: 'http://google.com/',

            start: '2017-01-28',

            className: 'event-coral'

        }

    ],

    viewRender: function(view, element) {

        // ÐŸÑ€Ð¸ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐºÐ»ÑŽÑ‡ÐµÐ½Ð¸Ð¸ Ð²Ð¸Ð´Ð° Ð¸Ð½Ð¸Ñ†Ð¸Ð°Ð»Ð¸Ð·Ð¸Ñ€ÑƒÐµÐ¼ Ð½ÐµÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð´Ð°Ñ€Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐºÑ€Ð¾Ð»Ð»

        if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {

            $('.fc-scroller').jScrollPane({

                autoReinitialise: true,

                autoReinitialiseDelay: 100

            });

        }



        $('.fc-popover.click').remove();

    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {



        var eventEl = $(this);



        // Add and remove event border class

        if (!$(this).hasClass('event-clicked')) {

            $('.fc-event').removeClass('event-clicked');



            $(this).addClass('event-clicked');

        }



        // Add popover

        $('body').append(

            '<div class="fc-popover click">' +

                '<div class="fc-header">' +

                    moment(calEvent.start).format('dddd â€¢ D') +

                    '<button type="button" class="cl"><i class="font-icon-close-2"></i></button>' +

                '</div>' +



                '<div class="fc-body main-screen">' +

                    '<p>' +

                        moment(calEvent.start).format('dddd, D YYYY, hh:mma') +

                    '</p>' +

                    '<p class="color-blue-grey">Name Surname Patient<br/>Surgey ACL left knee</p>' +

                    '<ul class="actions">' +

                        '<li><a href="#">More details</a></li>' +

                        '<li><a href="#" class="fc-event-action-edit">Edit event</a></li>' +

                        '<li><a href="#" class="fc-event-action-remove">Remove</a></li>' +

                    '</ul>' +

                '</div>' +



                '<div class="fc-body remove-confirm">' +

                    '<p>Are you sure to remove event?</p>' +

                    '<div class="text-center">' +

                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm">Yes</button>' +

                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-default remove-popover">No</button>' +

                    '</div>' +

                '</div>' +



                '<div class="fc-body edit-event">' +

                    '<p>Edit event</p>' +

                    '<div class="form-group">' +

                        '<div class="input-group date datetimepicker">' +

                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" />' +

                            '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="font-icon font-icon-calend"></i></span>' +

                        '</div>' +

                    '</div>' +

                    '<div class="form-group">' +

                        '<div class="input-group date datetimepicker-2">' +

                            '<input type="text" class="form-control" />' +

                            '<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="font-icon font-icon-clock"></i></span>' +

                        '</div>' +

                    '</div>' +

                    '<div class="form-group">' +

                        '<textarea class="form-control" rows="2">Name Surname Patient Surgey ACL left knee</textarea>' +

                    '</div>' +

                    '<div class="text-center">' +

                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm">Save</button>' +

                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-sm btn-default remove-popover">Cancel</button>' +

                    '</div>' +

                '</div>' +

            '</div>'

        );



        // Datepicker init

        $('.fc-popover.click .datetimepicker').datetimepicker({

            widgetPositioning: {

                horizontal: 'right'

            }

        });



        $('.fc-popover.click .datetimepicker-2').datetimepicker({

            widgetPositioning: {

                horizontal: 'right'

            },

            format: 'LT',

            debug: true

        });





        // Position popover

        function posPopover(){

            $('.fc-popover.click').css({

                left: eventEl.offset().left + eventEl.outerWidth()/2,

                top: eventEl.offset().top + eventEl.outerHeight()

            });

        }



        posPopover();



        $('.fc-scroller, .calendar-page-content, body').scroll(function(){

            posPopover();

        });



        $(window).resize(function(){

           posPopover();

        });





        // Remove old popover

        if ($('.fc-popover.click').length > 1) {

            for (var i = 0; i < ($('.fc-popover.click').length - 1); i++) {

                $('.fc-popover.click').eq(i).remove();

            }

        }



        // Close buttons

        $('.fc-popover.click .cl, .fc-popover.click .remove-popover').click(function(){

            $('.fc-popover.click').remove();

            $('.fc-event').removeClass('event-clicked');

        });



        // Actions link

        $('.fc-event-action-edit').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();



            $('.fc-popover.click .main-screen').hide();

            $('.fc-popover.click .edit-event').show();

        });



        $('.fc-event-action-remove').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();



            $('.fc-popover.click .main-screen').hide();

            $('.fc-popover.click .remove-confirm').show();

        });

    }

});





    /* ==========================================================================

Side datepicker


 ========================================================================== */



$('#side-datetimepicker').datetimepicker({

    inline: true,

    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

});



          /* ========================================================================== */



});





   /* ==========================================================================

Calendar page grid

========================================================================== */



    (function($, viewport){

$(document).ready(function() {



    if(viewport.is('>=lg')) {

        $('.calendar-page-content, .calendar-page-side').matchHeight();

    }



    // Execute code each time window size changes

    $(window).resize(

        viewport.changed(function() {

            if(viewport.is('<lg')) {

                $('.calendar-page-content, .calendar-page-side').matchHeight({ remove: true });

            }

        })

    );

});

    })(jQuery, ResponsiveBootstrapToolkit);
    //=========================================


    The calendar is supposed to show events in the day blocks and date picker, but it is not.
```

Please help!

Comment: please properly format the code

Comment: Done. Kindly advise.

Comment: Is there a difference in browsers? Or browser versions?

Comment: I just noticed that the same problem shows in Microsoft edge - desktop version, while on mobile version of chrome it works flawlessly.
I guess it might be a problem with my laptop then. Cause I tried that on my mini laptop and it also worked well!

Comment: Let me ask then: What if I wanted to retrieve events from the database instead of feeding them manually in the block? how will that work?

Comment: For those scenarios, see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/